# Excel formula contains =+

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula like this:

`=+SUMSQ(B14:B45)-MMULT(TRANSPOSE(L13:L16);K58:K61)`

What does do `=+` operator in Excel?
How to use it?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. It is a throwback to Lotus formulas and does no harm but is completely unnecessary. The equals sign is necessary to use a function but the plus sign is redundant.

Comment: @Jeeped Might as well post this as answer plus if a possible link or documentation is available, that would be great. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What does the **=+** do in this formula? `=+SUMSQ(B14:B45)`

Absolutely nothing. It is a throwback to Lotus style formulas and does no harm but is completely unnecessary. The equals sign at the left side is necessary to initiate the use of a worksheet function but the plus sign is redundant. The formula could just as easily be written as `=SUMSQ(B14:B45)`.

That said, do not confuse this with a double-minus (e.g. -- or [double unary](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-excel/what-is-the-doing-in-the-following-formula/7b510b48-59de-4586-814a-6940e6e926f4)). This is typically intended to convert a TRUE/FALSE result to a numerical one by mathematically flipping the sign (positive/negative nature of result) with the first minus then flipping it back with the second. In this way, a TRUE becomes a **1** and a FALSE a **0**. While its predominant use is conversion of boolean values to numerical, the double unary can also be used to convert text that looks like a number to an actual number; e.g. `=--RIGHT("ABC123", 3)` is equal to **123**, not text that looks like 123.

See [Overview of Formulas](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-formulas-d258ec72-149a-42ac-8eae-b50a667eb491) for more information on the construction of formulas.