# A formula in my worksheet starts with =+ what does that mean?

Tags: excel

basically i want to change the exam grades in my worksheet which is currently 25% to 50%. Apparently the formula in term 1 is correct, which means its giving 50%, but its giving 25% in term 2.although the formula in both the terms is exactly same.

Comment: could you please post some more details? it might be helpful if we want to solve the problem. Some code snippets maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel formula contains =+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683723/excel-formula-contains)

Answer (score 1):

Without any more detail, it's hard to know what your formulas are doing - but the `=+` in a formula doesn't really mean anything, it's the same as just using an `=` sign. `=+1+1` will show "2", `=+5+5` will show 10.  `=+5*2` will show 10, then automatically remove the "+" sign.  I suppose it could be used/thought of as an explicit "positive" number attribution?

Edit: You can Google around for a better answer, I found this one on [Mr. Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/369789-why-do-some-people-use-plus-sign-beginning-formulas.html):

"The '+' character is a backwards-compatible effort by Microsoft to accommodate formula entry by people who were former Lotus users, in long ago days when Lotus was the dominant spreadsheet program and MS was building their customer base.

Given the premise of the question being 'why use it and why is it there', my understanding of the '+' character's genesis and existence in Excel formulas is rooted in compatibility with other programs. It's there because Microsoft was in a battle with Lotus and other programs some 15 years ago for spreadsheet marketshare dominance, and incorporated features like this for compatibility, just as REM and some BASIC statements are still supported in VBA.

Though the '+' character has a coercive effect in some formulas, one would typically not employ or be advised to rely on the preceding '+' as a general strategy for coercion before employing +0, *1, or --.

Most times when I see a formula with a preceding '+' character, it's composed by an ex-Lotus convert." - Tom Urtis

Also someone else points out a NumPad seldom has an "=" so Excel can use "+" instead. `=2+2` is the same in Excel as `+2+2` in a cell.