# Returning Second result using Index in Excel

Tags: excel, indexing

I am currently using this formula to return my results. But it is only returning the first value. I am finding that there are multiple results that I need to review.

How do I change it to return the second or third result?

```
=+IFERROR(+INDEX(WU!$S$2:$S$20000,MATCH(1,(WU!$C$2:$C$20000=$C5)*(WU!$O$2:$O$20000=$H$1),0))," ")
```

Using Windows 7-Office 2016
Thanks,

Comment: Match function finds the first instance of the value only. Also, the [`=+` notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683723/excel-formula-contains) really is deprecated by about 20 years and you should consider avoiding it if for no other reason than to make your formulas more legible :)

Answer (score 1):

Use AGGREGATE/ROW instead of MATCH:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(WU!$S:$S,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(WU!$C$2:$C$20000)/((WU!$C$2:$C$20000=$C5)*(WU!$O$2:$O$20000=$H$1)),2))
```

This is not a CSE array formula so enter normally.

This will return the second, change the `2` at the end to `3` to get the third and so on.

You can also change the `2` to `ROW(1:1)` and it will automatically increase to the next as you copy/drag the formula down.