# Count If With Less Than Not Working - Excel

Tags: excel, countif, inequality

trying to perform a simple Count If calculation, testing if cells are less than 1000. Roughly half the column's values are less than 1000, but it only returns 0.

Code: =COUNTIF($O:$O, "<1000")

Anyone know that the problem is? Thanks in advance!

Comment: the 'numbers' in column o are not true numbers; they are text that look like numbers. use text to columns. fixed width, finish.

Comment: That appears to be it. Do you know a way around it? The values in that column use the equation =RIGHT(B2, 4).

Comment: try `=--RIGHT(B2, 4)`

Comment: That works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The 'numbers' in column o are not true numbers; they are text that look like numbers. Any text, even a zero length string like `""` will be greater than a true number.

A formula like `=RIGHT(B2, 4)` returns text. This is evidenced by the default left cell alignment.

Convert the formula's result to a true number with a '[double unary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683723/excel-formula-contains/28697814#28697814)' or 'double minus'.

```
=--right(b2, 4)
```